# autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why am I getting "autocomplete is not a function"? Does JQ still support it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="" ><head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"</script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>            
</head>
<body>
    <input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("myInput").autocomplete({//<<###################
                source: [
                    { label: "India", value: "IND" },
                    { label: "Australia", value: "AUS" }
                ]
            });        
        });//$(document).ready(function ()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: autocomplete is a jQuery method, not a native Element method.  You are trying to call it on a non-jQuery object

Comment: @Taplar Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!   $("#myInput").autocomplete   works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Taplar's comment, you can't call `autocomplete` on a native element object. You need to call it on a jQuery-object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myInput").autocomplete({
            source: [
                { label: "India", value: "IND" },
                { label: "Australia", value: "AUS" }
            ]
        });          
});
```